# What are omics journals?

Tags: journals

My supervisor asked me to do a survey from -omics journals. I am however unsure as to what he means by -omics journals because a google search only gives me information about the predatory publishing group "omics journals". He said that one of the two I provided, Genome Research and Nature Genetics is a omics journal. I am wondering if he meant a journal ending in -ome is an -omics journal. I did not ask him because I did not want to appear ignorant.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omics

Comment: @Penguin_Knight, wikipedia knows all - tells all.

Comment: @Buffy It does apparently. I am just waiting for an answer to close the question. You can write down an answer if interested.

Comment: Actually, "closing" a question means something radically different here, shutting off future answers. Accepting is a bit different. But you could also up vote @Penguin_Knight for quick research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Nature Genetics* is a reputable journal that might publish papers in the category of "genomics," which itself is a subset of "omics." Broadly, omics encompasses the quantification and analysis of various biological components – for example, *metabolomics* uses LC-MS systems to quantify different *metabolites* (e.g. tacrolimus degradation products for therapeutic drug monitoring in kidney transplant patients). [Genomics](https://www.genome.gov/18016863/a-brief-guide-to-genomics/) analyzes the genome, which includes all the genes we have.

[OMICS Publishing Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMICS_Publishing_Group) is considered a predatory publisher due to an apparent lack of legitimacy in their peer-review process, excessive publishing fees, and fraudulent behaviors as described in [Predatory Publishing – Experience 
with OMICS International](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5723186/pdf/MA-71-304.pdf) (Masic, *MED ARCH.* 2017). However, *Genome Research* is published by Cold Spring Harbor Lab Press, which is from a legitimate institution.

Searching for [`"genome research" "omics international"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22genome+research%22+%22omics+international%22) brings up OMICS' *Journal of Genome*, Human Genome Research Articles page, and Genome Research review page, so I don't think they have a journal called *Genome Research*.

Your mentor is asking you to review articles from genomics journals like *Genomics*, *Cytogenetic and Genome Research*, *Genome*, *Nature Reviews Genetics*, *BMC Genomics*, *Journal of Human Genetics* and others that you can [easily find](https://www.google.com/search?q=genomics+journals).

A final aside: [Last November](https://www.the-scientist.com/the-nutshell/us-court-issues-injunction-against-open-access-publisher-omics-30581), the FTC won an initial court ruling against OMICS International for their deceptive practices. Do your due diligence as you complete your literature survey and stay vigilant against unethical and irresponsible publishers.

These topics are relevant to my home institution (University of Colorado): [Jeff Beall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffrey_Beall) was sued by OMICS for raising these allegations several years ago, and I just watched [Eric Green](https://www.genome.gov/27527308/about-the-director/) (director of the NIH Human Genome Research Initiative) speak at my program's national conference last Sunday.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you last guess seems to be correct! See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omics